# I am testing out developing a discord bot, but ctx.guild.owner returns none in the embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="#", intents=intents)

@bot.command()

async def server(ctx):
name = str(ctx.guild.name)
description = str(ctx.guild.description)

```
owner = str(ctx.guild.owner)
id = str(ctx.guild.id)
region = str(ctx.guild.region)
memberCount = str(ctx.guild.member_count)

icon = str(ctx.guild.icon_url)

embed = discord.Embed(
    title=name + " Server Information",
    description=description,
    color=discord.Color.blue()
)
embed.set_thumbnail(url=icon)
embed.add_field(name="Owner", value=owner, inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="Server ID", value=id, inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="Region", value=region, inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="Member Count", value=memberCount, inline=True)

await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

this is my full code, and it doesn't really work please help :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that ctx.guild.owner returns none.

The reason is that ctx.guild.owner is a property that returns the guild owner.

The guild owner is not always present in the guild, so it may return none.

You should be able to fix this by using the following code:

```
if ctx.guild.owner is not None:
    owner = str(ctx.guild.owner)
    id = str(ctx.guild.id)
    region = str(ctx.guild.region)
    memberCount = str(ctx.guild.member_count)
    icon = str(ctx.guild.icon_url)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=name + " Server Information",
        description=description,
        color=discord.Color.blue()
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=icon)
    embed.add_field(name="Owner", value=owner, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Server ID", value=id, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Region", value=region, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Member Count", value=memberCount, inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This will make sure that the guild owner is present in the guild, and if it is not, it will not return an error.

Comment: And how could I do that? I thought that "embed.add_field(name="Owner", value=owner, inline=True)" did that.

Comment: @MarlonInno made an edit to the awnser, hope this works for you!

Comment: @lebi376 In `owner = str(ctx.guild.owner)` it returns an object of the owner itself. In order to print out the owner in an embed in `embed.add_field(name="Owner", value=owner, inline=True)`, either change to `value=owner.name` (returns the owner's Discord username) or to `value=owner.mention` (mentions the owner)